# Zoom MKMapview to closest two MKAnnotations for current user location

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, mapkit

What is the best way to zoom an MKMapview to closest two or three MKAnnotations for current user location?

I have a list of GPS coordinates (328 to be precise) loaded from a plist, every point is an annotation on the map. I'd like to limit the view to the two nearest annotation points around the user's current location.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, the steps would be:

1. Find current location, convert to MKMapPoint
2. Iterate your list of annotations, using `MKMetersBetweenMapPoints` to find distance from current location
3. Save 2 or 3 smallest distances
4. Use the largest of these three distances to make a region using `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`
5. Center the map on current location
6. Zoom to the region using `[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE]`

Comment: If the points were to one side of the user location it would mean a lot of the map space was wasted by having equal distance on both sides of the user location. If you're happy to have the user location closer to the edge of a the map you could instead loop though your three closest points and user location getting the outer boundary then add some padding and use that in setRegion.