# Getting which contacts are close to my current location?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm experimenting with an app for my own use, and trying to find an energy efficient way to get the Contacts whose addresses are close to my current location.

There are about 100 people in my Contacts list each located in another town, maybe 5-60 km apart. Essentially after I've visited about 5-6 of them I'm running out of time and I just want the next two or three to be really close to my location.

What I'm doing now, requesting directions by selecting a Contact manually and seeing how much time it would take to get there, which is fine... But as the client list grows I have trouble remembering which ones are close and I keep selecting them and never get it right.

I tried storing them in an NSDictionary and grouping them by locality but it would be great to have a simple radar like report where the program would "see" which points are close just as one is able to figure out immediately by looking at a map whith 20 placemarks.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean simply a map showing the location of each contact?

Comment: I already can lay them out on a map, but as I move and visit them I would like the next closest three to "light" up as possible next visits.

Comment: It's as if I have a halo region of 120min of drive time, some 70km, around my current location and everything inside that is displayed in another color.

Comment: I see. The problem is `drive time`, since this will vary in different directions. If you simply specify this as the distance in a straight line then I think MapKit has some methods for determining the distance between the device and a specified point on the map.

Comment: I see, you are right maybe I'm not simplifying the problem enough. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412379/zoom-mkmapview-to-closest-two-mkannotations-for-current-user-location along the line of your suggestion.

Comment: That's a start. What you could do is iterate over say the 10 geographically closest points, calculate the driving time to them and then highlight the one with the shortest drive time. That should cover most cases (Assuming you live in a fairly normally designed city) and be relatively quick.

Answer (score 0):

How does [`-distanceToLocation:` (iOS Developer Library)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:) sound to you?

From the comments I understand that you have the locations of all contacts. So you just need to loop through the contacts, get the distance to your current location and compare them...

You could possibly make an array or dictionary of `CLLocation` and `CLLocationDistance` objects and sort them by the distance.